# Alternative of Azure elastic query?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We are having 20 database in Azure. From First database we are using Azure elastic query to fetch employee details from each database to show in ui. But elastic query is taking  taking lot of time for only 500 rows.
Is there any alternative way to handle cross database querying in Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-DB query in SQL Server is generally a lot faster than Elastic Query.  If you want cross-database queries in a PaaS service, please consider SQL Azure Managed Instance which supports multiple databases per instance like SQL Server does.  You will find the cross-db perf to be similar to SQL Server cross-db intra-instance queries.

Best of luck

Comment: Managed Instance can resolve this issue but we have setup up in elastic pool of Paas service. Changing the infrastructure to managed pool required lot of approvals from business heads so was wondering if there is any way to do cross database querying without using elastic query

Comment: The only options you have are similar in perf to Elastic Query - for example, you could set up SQL Server in a VM and create linked servers across each SQL DB in your pool.

Comment: Thanks we are also thinking to move from Paas to VM